# OBIEE: Hidden report issue

Tags: report, hidden, catalog, obiee

In OBIEE, I can see the my report when I using by search button. But I can not see the same report in its folder. I controlled the report privileges, folder properties etc.. What should I do, please help..

Answer (score 0):

When you're in the catalog view, there's a checkbox in the top-right corner to "Show Hidden Items". I've seen that catch a few people out.

Answer (score 0):

Begin by assuming that your assumption is incorrect.

Assumption: You have already controlled the report privileges, folder properties etc.

I suspect there may be permissions that have not been propagated down from the containing folder to the object. Check the permissions on the object's folder and compare them with the the permissions of the object itself.

But if your assumption is true, and there is nothing in the object's properties or permissions that could cause the symptom you are seeing, I would recommend reading thoroughly through the Oracle documentation about [catalog management](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E28280_01/bi.1111/e10541/prescatadmin.htm) for troubleshooting ideas.

Additionally, you can run [catalog validation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E28280_01/bi.1111/e10541/prescatadmin.htm#BIESG3584) and other processes to rule out inconsistencies in your BI catalog as a cause of this issue.